# How to show/hide elements based on radio selection

Tags: angular

I'm working on an Angular project and I want to create a structure in which a visitor can click through a number of questions. Depending on the selected radio button another element should show.

In AngularJS you could use

```
<input id="first1" type="radio" name="content" ng-model="contentTemplate" value="first">
```

and

```
<p ng-show="contentTemplate == 'first'">This is the first content!</p>
```

to show the element but this doesn't seem to be working in Angular2.

I've created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mr3zPiwtWqXv5oRP3Sp5?p=preview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't use Plunkr (corporate proxy) but you need to bind your radio to your model like so

```
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="yourBoolean">
<div *ngIf="yourBoolean"></div>
```

Don't forget to import `FormsModule` to make ngModel work

Comment: Do you mean `import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';  `? or another sort of ngForms? Can't find much on Google about ngForms.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not very clear, I mix things up with angularJS. I meant `FormsModule`

Comment: Nice ! Remember to mark your topic as resolved then.